# Pie Chart on Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

[Screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDDEl.png)
I want to plot pie chart on Google map. My code is working fine on chrome but in IE 11 when number of pie chart >50 then its take a huge time.

In chrome its working fine I have tested with more than 100 pie charts.

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

```
function drawPieCharts() {

var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.0902, 95.7129);
var map = new google.maps.Map($('#mapUsers')[0], {
    zoom: 2,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function () {

});
var data;
var options;
var marker;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Dashboard.aspx/GetCyberRiskViewMap",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var ChartSourceobj = JSON.parse(data.d);
        for (var i = 1; i < ChartSourceobj.length ; i++) {
            latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(ChartSourceobj[i].latitude, ChartSourceobj[i].longitude);
            data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
               ['Events', 'User Events'],
               ['Malicious', ChartSourceobj[i].malicious_count],
               ['Suspicious', ChartSourceobj[i].suspicious_count],
               ['New', ChartSourceobj[i].new_count]

            ]);

            options = {
                fontSize: 10,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                datalessRegionColor: '#abafb8',
                legend: 'none',
                pieSliceText: 'none',
                slices: { 0: { color: '#FE2E2E' }, 1: { color: '#FF8000' }, 2: { color: '#FACC2E' } }

            };

            marker = new ChartMarker({
                map: map,
                position: latLng,
                width: '80px',
                height: '80px',
                chartData: data,
                chartOptions: options,
                events: {
                    click: function (event) {

                    }
                }
            });

        }

    },
    error: function (data) {

    }
});
```

};

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please let me know if you need additional information

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with your code. It's just that each browser deals with the DOM in their own way. It depends a lot in the inner workings of that `ChartMaker`you're using, if it uses Canvas, SVG, or whatever. Every DOM element takes its toll in the browser performance.